# Adopting CSLA.NET on started project

Tags: c#, csla

Im considering use CSLA.NET 3.8 for example for Security and Identity Management on a started Windows Forms Fx 3.5 Project, this will be considered as a good practice?

Im looking for :

### - Namespace : Csla.Security

- MembershipIdentity
- BusinessPrincipalBase

### - Namespace : Csla

- BusinessBase
- PropertyInfo

My question is about how much will cost on a started project to adopt this framework if the security schemma is not defined yet (on the solution) and Where to begin to deal with this (I mean, how to attack the changes or be ready for any real complex refactorization), I'm worried about this issue, cause I see that CSLA.NET is so complex, but If anyone will share experiences I'll be glad

---

Any response will be helpfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSLA and I do not get along so I may be the wrong person to answer this.  We've been useing a small portion of it at work for about two years and spend a great deal of time being annoyed by it.  I would recommend you weigh other options.  just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend checking out our [CSLA 3.8 templates](http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/downloads/list). They come in both a VB.NET and a C# flavor. We provide a means for active generation and generate authorization rules with partial method hooks for complete customizations. This makes customizing your rules a breeze. Since its template based you could refactor the template, regenerate and make your rule changes in seconds instead of hours or days.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))